# How best to reuse the same stored procedure for details and summary

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Given a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure BigParameterizedSearch(@criteria xml, @page int, @pageSize int)
as
    ...lots of populating table variables & transforming things...

    select ..bunch of columns..
    from   ..bunch of tables..
    where  ..bunch of (@has_some_filter=0 or ..some filter criteria..) and..
    order by ..big case statement depends on criteria..
    offset (@page-1)*@pageSize rows
    fetch next @pageSize rows only
    option (recompile)
```

and its 'summary' counterpart:

```
create procedure BigParameterizedSearchSummary(@criteria xml, @page int, @pageSize int)
as
    ...same exact populating table variables & transforming things...

    select groupCol, ..various aggregates..
    from   ..same exact bunch of tables..
    where  ..same exact bunch of (@has_some_filter=0 or ..some filter criteria..) and..
    group by groupCol
    order by ..smaller case statement depends on criteria..
    offset (@page-1)*@pageSize rows
    fetch next @pageSize rows only
    option (recompile)
```

The two stored procedures are largely the same, only the `select` clause and `order by` clause is different, and the 'summary' version adds a `group by`.

Now, the question is, how could these two stored procedures be combined? Or, how otherwise could the duplicate code be avoided? I have tried in vain to create a common table-valued-function with `returns table as return` so that the select and group by could be pulled out to calling stored procedures without impacting performance. The restrictions on `returns table as return` makes it too difficult to perform all of the complicated setup, and if I make it populate a table variable then the full result set is populated for each page which slows it down too much. Is there any other strategy aside from going full dynamic SQL?

Comment: Why is avoiding duplicate code such a high priority? In many languages "don't repeat yourself" is a worthwhile mantra, but in SQL Server, it doesn't have quite the same payoff. You could do this with dynamic SQL perhaps, but the cost in maintenance might be higher than maintaining two separate procedures.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree and I went with repeating myself for now and posted this question since I couldn't find a better way. The setup code and where clause is ~300 lines and 99% of the stored procedure so it would be very nice to eliminate the redundancy.

Comment: Without *actual* code and understanding what on earth you mean by "restrictions on return as return makes it too difficult" then I would say dynamic SQL is your best option if you really want to trade one maintainability problem for another.

Comment: You can use one table function, and two SPs that call same function. Often it's important to place business logic in one place rather than duplicate it.

Comment: As for avoiding populating a table variable with all the results, have you seen [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch), which focuses on finding the *clustering key* values in the current page only, and then only pulling the full set of wider data for those key values? Your current approach pulls all the matching data every time, and then filters to the rows for the current page, which is expensive.

Comment: @Anton a table-valued function *might* be possible, but won't necessarily support all of the query elements in the real code.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for optimization opportunities, `@criteria xml` is ***screaming*** for attention.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's the restrictions on `returns table as return` - had a typo. Basically it has to be a single statement, so all the setup populating table variables has to be rewritten as common table expressions - and it kills performance. What better alternative for `@criteria xml` for passing a bunch of arbitrary filter settings?

Comment: Table-valued parameters. Maybe. Again, without specifics from your side, I can only fling out generalizations from my side. I just know that shredding XML is just about the slowest thing SQL Server does.

Comment: I could replace `criteria xml` with no less than 20 table-valued parameters.. if I did that then it might be more possible to implement the common `returns table as return` function without killing performance. I will give it a try..

Comment: Also all of the `@has_some_filter=0 or ..some filter criteria..` seems to be begging for dynamic SQL, too. See [this article](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/). So with dynamic SQL you may kill two birds with one stone (code reuse and better plans optimized for the set of actual parameters in use).

Comment: `option(recompile)` works well with the `@has_some_filter=0` stuff.. I really have no complaints about the performance of this sproc, just the duplicate code

Comment: I have to ask - is this for a report? perhaps you do the summarising in the report layer? or is this your actual report layer?

Comment: But you don't necessarily need to recompile that entire query if you have a version that exists for when filter A is used and a different version that exists for when filter B is used. You should only need to recompile when you have a specific parameter that is sensitive to skew based on different values. This is different from presence or absence of a parameter value.

Comment: Nick, it's a generic search that powers a variety of things including reports. there's no reporting layer here. Aaron, the recompile cost is very low relative to the query and seems well worth the overhead for any plan improvement due to statistical insights.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view that contains all the columns from all the tables with all the filters you would need for both queries and then do your selects and groupings against that view.  That would save you on the issue of redundancy if I understand your situation correctly.  Honestly this sort of issue is exactly what views are for.

Also, I am just curious, do you really need to recompile every time?  Is there something incredible going on that you can't afford to use a cached execution plan?

Comment: it's a big parameterized search so using a plan from some other set of parameters would almost always be a disaster, plus the overhead of the recompile is well worth the gains in plan optimization based on statistical insights. As for making a view - it's not possible to do the necessary setup involving populating various table variables in a view definition. I have tried as a table-valued-function and mentioned by challenges with that in the question.

Comment: Understandable, but you can still put all your table joins in a view along with all the columns you want to return and have the filters outside the view.  Not sure if that would really buy you anything.  Catch-all queries for everything generally suck but I know sometimes it's just what you get stuck with.  The worst one I worked on was converted to dynamic sql because that was the only way to get good plan caching and acceptable performance ... that was something like 200M records and ~20 different sets of filters used to query.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just split this into a sproc that populates the tables and a sproc that calls the table population using the same parameters and then queries the tables?

```
create table Prepop (a int)
go

create procedure uspPopulate (@StartNum int)
as
truncate table Prepop
insert into Prepop values
 (@StartNum)
,(@StartNum+1)
,(@StartNum+2)
,(@StartNum+3)
go

create procedure uspCall (@StartNum int, @Summary bit)
as
exec uspPopulate @StartNum = @StartNum
if @Summary = 1
    select avg(a) as Avga
    from Prepop
else
    select a
    from Prepop
go

exec uspCall @StartNum = 6, @Summary = 1
exec uspCall @StartNum = 6, @Summary = 0
```

Comment: the problem with this is that I'm using `offset .. fetch next` to quickly retrieve a one page of results and if I populate a table with all of the results every time I grab a page then things get a lot slower. I also tried putting both versions on either side of a `if @summary=1` but the statement after a CTE cannot be an if so I would end up having to repeat the entire where clause and CTE setup.. it is a way to eliminate the redundant table variable setup however

Comment: @gordy  What's stopping you using the `offset` and `fetch` in the sprocs?  Can you post your script in it's entirety?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer, I thought you were suggesting to populate a results table but I see you are suggesting using permanent tables instead of table variables for the setup. That's an interesting idea and would allow them to be populated by some common sproc.. I worry about concurrency though - perhaps temp tables would be better.

Comment: @gordy Temporary tables only work within the session they are created, so you would need to use global temp tables (prefixed with `##`) if you want to pass them between sprocs, though these would have the same concurrency issue.  If you could post your script, you'd get much better answers.